# Dovecot not loading sieve or not filtering

Tags: debian, dovecot

```
root@debian11:/etc/dovecot# dovecot -n
# 2.3.13 (89f716dc2): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.13 (cdd19fe3)
# OS: Linux 5.10.0-26-amd64 x86_64 Debian 11.8
# Hostname: localhost
auth_username_format = %n
listen = 127.0.0.1, ::1
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_default = /etc/dovecot/sieve/global/default.sieve
  sieve_global = /etc/dovecot/sieve/global/
  sieve_max_redirects = 30
}
protocols = " imap sieve pop3 sieve"
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
```

and only this in log

```
Nov 06 23:46:41 master: Info: Dovecot v2.3.13 (89f716dc2) starting up for imap, sieve, pop3, sieve (core dumps disabled)
```

and roundcube success connecting to managesieve

in messages have headers like

```
X-Spam_score: -5.2
X-Spam_bar: ---
```

exim4+dovecot+mailroundcube+spamassasin

other logs

```
Nov  6 23:02:00 localhost dovecot: managesieve(admin)<258896><89DBU4EJyJp/AAAB>: Disconnected: Logged out bytes=54/518

Nov 6 23:01:29 localhost roundcube: <3muamjlk> S: OK "Dovecot (Debian) ready."
```

roundcube creating new filters in WEB UI, but not working and roundcube creating roundcube.sieve and symlink.. I also created a global script, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying that Roundcube can successfully connect to the managesieve service?

Comment: Why have you got `sieve` listed twice under protocols?

Comment: Nov  6 23:01:29 localhost roundcube: <3muamjlk> S: OK "Dovecot (Debian) ready."
like this

Comment: I've tried three places sieve

Comment: Dumping log information isn't really answering what I've asked

Comment: roundcube creating new filters in WEB UI, but not working and roundcube
creating roundcube.sieve and symlink..
I also created a global script, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think it should say(googled): t dovecot: lda: Debug: Module loaded:
/usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib90_sieve_plugin.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Dovecot is correctly offering and managing a Sieve service. You will need to adjust your (unspecified) Mail Delivery Agent to use the Sieve file/service for message delivery.

Comment: what else do I have to install?

Comment: something that delivers mail

Comment: examples please

Comment: postfix sendmail exim4

Comment: I already have exim4 so I didn't understand it right away, I will config it.